# How to fix a while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've seen that usually, the mistake occurs when you use while inside of a while loop, however, it's not the case here, so I'm asking for help with this "common" mistake

> The following part of the code is not important, probably you can just
>   ignore it

```
crd = ['1 3', '2 3', '3 3', '1 2', '2 2', '3 2', '1 1', '2 1', '3 1']
inp = list(input('Enter cells:'))
wins = 0
result = False


def field(val):
    print('---------')
    for i in range(0, 9, 3):
        print('| ' + '{} {} {}'.format(val[i], val[i+1], val[i+2]).replace('_', ' ') + ' |')
    print('---------')


def win(con):
    global wins
    global result
    if inp[0] == '_':
        result = 'Impossible'
    else:
        win_con = [[con[i], con[i+1], con[i+2]] for i in range(0, 9, 3)] \
                + [[con[i], con[i+3], con[i+6]] for i in range(0, 3, 1)]\
                + [[con[0], con[4], con[8]], [con[2], con[4], con[6]]]

        for i in win_con:
            if (set(i) == {'X'} or set(i) == {'O'}) and wins == 1:
                result = 'Impossible'
            elif set(i) == {'X'}:
                result = 'X wins'
                wins = 1
            elif set(i) == {'O'}:
                result = 'O wins'
                wins = 1

        if result == False:
            try:
                inp.index('_')
                result = 'Game not finished'
            except:
                result = 'Draw'
    print(result)


field(inp)
```

> Bellow is the part of the code with a loop that returns Infinite loop
>   mistake (as far as I understood the mistake is in def move() part

```
def move():
    move = input('Enter the coordinates:').split(' ')
    while True:
        for n in move:
            if int(n) not in range(1, 4):
                print('Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!')
                move = input('Enter the coordinates:').split(' ')
                continue
            elif int(n) in range(1, 4):
                move = ' '.join(move)
                break


while True:
    move()
    position = [p for p, x in enumerate(crd) if x == move]
    int_pos = int("".join([str(p) for p in position]))

    if inp[int_pos] == '0' or inp[int_pos] == 'X':
        print('This cell is occupied! Choose another one!')
        move()
    elif inp[int_pos] == '_':
        inp[int_pos] = 'X'
        field(inp)
        win(inp)
    if result:
        break
```

> Somehow, once I even managed to fix the infinite loop mistake, nevertheless, a different issue occurred - after checking the first pair of coordinates (and showing that they are out of range) It took input for new pair of coordinates but still proceed to check old pair of coordinates that were already checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are using function move just to input a valid coords right
you can simplify it as follows

```py
def input_coordinates():
    while True:
        x, y = [int(i) for i in input('Enter the coordinates:').split(' ')]
        if (1 <= x < 4
              and 1 <= y < 4):
           return x, y
        # this will keep looping unless you get valid coordinates
```

Then you write you main like this

```py
while True:
    x, y = input_coordinates()
    move = "{} {}".format(x, y) # formatting the way you expect it.
    position = [p for p, x in enumerate(crd) if x == move]
    int_pos = int("".join([str(p) for p in position]))

    if inp[int_pos] == '0' or inp[int_pos] == 'X':
        print('This cell is occupied! Choose another one!')
        continue
    elif inp[int_pos] == '_':
        inp[int_pos] = 'X'
        field(inp)
        win(inp)
    if result:
        break
```

1. Try to avoid global variables,
2. you also had a conflict you had string and function both with the name "move"
3. you didn't need to add one more iteration (`for n in move`) in you original move() function

Comment: Awesome, Got it! Thank you for your detailed reply.